# Normalizar Base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Me gustaría que me ayuden a normalizar una base de datos, tenemos un proyecto de registro de mascotas, la mascota tiene un propietario, el propietario tiene un tipo de documento, como DNI, PASAPORTE, CARNET DE EXTRANJERÍA, a ver si me ayudan a desglosarlo, dejo runa imagen de lo que estoy haciendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas preguntas concretas. Como por ejemplo que nivel de normalizacion tiene una tabla de la que expresas. o como llegar a X forma normal la siguienhte tabla. O por que X tabla no esta en X forma normal.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que pensar de una manera global, e intentar evitar repetir lo que más puedas, por ejemplo:

A simple vista tienes 3 entidades

- dni
- carnet extranjero
- pasaporte

Los cuales tienen exactamente los mismos atributos, y todos tienen una FK a tipo_doc, por lo que lo primero es pensar

- ¿corresponden a lo mismo?
- ¿podrá ser que mejor genero una entidad, y le agrego una columna de tipo para identificar?.

También pensar en cosas como:

- ¿la entidad esterilizado lo único que hace es indicar si/no? de ser así, es necesario que lo tengas como una entidad con FK, o podrías tenerlo dentro de la entidad mascota, y manejarlo directamente ahí.

Comment: normeno, si bien intentaste ayudar a un usuario, lo hiciste en forma de "opinión", lo cual está mal visto dentro de la comunidad. Es preferible a esto, un a solución concreta, y en último caso, si vas a dar una opinión, basarla en algún estándar de desarrollo. Te suguiero que sigas el [tour] para que puedas mejorar tus respuestas y preguntas futuras.